# I have short the URL Using .htaccess but every shortened URL goes to the same page

Tags: php, .htaccess

Let first read the code I have written in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ /pages/categories.php [END]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ /pages/cart.php [END]
```

I have used `.htaccess` for URL shortening. the first `RewriteRule` is used to shorten the URL of the `/pages/categories.php` to this URL `http://app.test/categories` and when I go to that URL it successfully goes to the `categories.php page`. The Second `RewriteRule` is used to shorten the URL of the `/pages/cart.php` to this URL `http://app.test/cart`. but when I go to this URL it also Shows the `categories.php` page. Not showing the `cart.php` page.

Comment: you rewrite rule is same for both url. Bcz of that when you enter cart url then it search into .htaccess & 1st url matches with condition thats why it will redirect to category

Comment: so how can I write it? I have tried many ways but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use different url for different pages:

```
RewriteRule ^categories$ /pages/categories.php [END]
RewriteRule ^cart$ /pages/cart.php [END]
```

It will redirect you on right pages.